# How to create pairs from a single column based on order of occurrence in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows:

```
timestamp,session,event
5/23/2016 13:00,1,A
5/23/2016 13:20,1,B
5/23/2016 13:40,1,C
5/23/2016 14:00,2,B
5/23/2016 15:00,2,C
5/23/2016 15:20,3,B
5/23/2016 15:40,3,C
5/23/2016 16:00,3,D
```

I am trying to build ordered pairs of events within a session sorted by timestamp. My objective is to build a data input for sankey charts which needs the following format:

```
start,end,value
A,B,1
B,C,3
C,D,1
```

I have not been able to figure this out yet. I can think of using recursive query within sqldf. But was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Sorry this is the first time I am posting for help on Stackoverflow and I could not figure out how to show the dataset, hence pasting pictures. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: I guess you need all the combinations.  In that case, try with `?combn`

Comment: No...your edit just made it hard to read ;(

Comment: Why is A C combination not needed?

Comment: @akrun I think he just wants to count single steps from one letter to the next, that is all.

Comment: @akrun: Trying combn now

Comment: @thelatemail: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I only need the combinations present in the data and not necessarily all the combinations. And A-C is not needed because it is covered by A to B followed by B to C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- cbind(dataset[1:nrow(dataset)-1,], dataset[2:nrow(dataset),])
names(df) <- c("timestamp1", "session1", "event1", "timestamp2", "session2", "event2")

> df %>% filter(session1==session2) %>% count(event1, event2)

Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: event1

  event1 event2 n
1      A      B 1
2      B      C 3
3      C      D 1
```

Comment: C-B should not be included in the result because I am only looking for ordered pairs in the same session

Comment: It isn't clear to me why `C-B` should be omitted.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: I am looking for instances WITHIN a session where B occurred after C. In the dataset sample above, no such instance occurred within a session. But given your solution it is an easy fix - I just need to filter rows for the condition session==session. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe one way to consider this is to interpret the first letter as a departure and the last letter as an arrival, which would obviously respect a chronological order. Those "trips" should be grouped according to the `session` variable. In this sense, the dataset does not contain a "departure" from C and an "arrival" to B within a given session.

Answer (score 3):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- na.omit(setDT(df1)[order(as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
 ][, end := shift(event, type="lead"), session][])
d1[,.(value=.N) ,.(start=event, end)]
#   start end value
#1:     A   B     1
#2:     B   C     3
#3:     C   D     1
```

---

Using the same methodology with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    arrange(as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
    group_by(session) %>%
    mutate(end = lead(event))  %>% 
    na.omit() %>%
    group_by(start=event, end) %>%
    summarise(value = n())
#     start   end value
#    <chr> <chr> <int>
#1     A     B     1
#2     B     C     3
#3     C     D     1
```