# How to create pairs from a single column counting the occurrence in R?

Tags: r, network-analysis, edge-list

So I'm working on creating an edges file for a social network analysis based on IMDb data.
And I've run into a problem and I can't figure out how to fix it as I'm new to R.

Assuming I have the following dataframe:

```
movieID <- c('A', 'A','A', 'B','B', 'C','C', 'C')
crewID <- c('Z', 'Y', 'X', 'Z','V','V', 'X', 'Y')
rating <- c('7.3','7.3', '7.3', '2.1', '2.1', '9.0','9.0', '9.0')
df <- data.frame(movieID, crewID, rating)
```

| movieID | CrewID | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Z | 7.3 |
| A | Y | 7.3 |
| A | X | 7.3 |
| B | Z | 2.1 |
| B | V | 2.1 |
| C | V | 9.0 |
| C | X | 9.0 |
| C | Y | 9.0 |

I am trying to build unique pairs of CrewIDs within a movie with a weight that equals the occurrence of that pair, meaning how often these two crew members have worked on a movie together. So basically I want a dataframe like the following as a result:

| CrewID1 | CrewID2 | weight | (not a col but explanation) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z | Y | 1 | together once in movie A |
| Z | X | 1 | together once in movie A |
| Y | X | 2 | together twice in movies A and C |
| Z | V | 1 | together once in movie B |
| V | X | 1 | together once in movie C |
| V | Y | 1 | together once in movie C |

The pairs (Z,Y) and (Y,Z) are equal to each other as I don't care about direction.

I found the following StackOverflow thread on a similar issue:
[How to create pairs from a single column based on order of occurrence in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428832/how-to-create-pairs-from-a-single-column-based-on-order-of-occurrence-in-r)

However in my case this skips the combination (V,Y) and (X,Z) and the count for (X,Y) is still 1 and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Could you share your first `data.frame` with `dput`?  This will make it easier for people to help you as they can copy paste code to read in a snippet of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m <- crossprod(table(df[-3]))
m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <-0
subset(as.data.frame.table(m), Freq > 0)

   CrewID CrewID.1 Freq
2       X        V    1
3       Y        V    1
4       Z        V    1
7       Y        X    2
8       Z        X    1
12      Z        Y    1
```

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your answer. This just seems to give me an empty matrice... Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Christine What do you mean by empty matrix? This gives the expected results

Comment: If I have a dataframe with the columns movieID <- c('A', 'A','A', 'B','B', 'C','C', 'C') and crewID <- c('Z', 'Y', 'X', 'Z','V','V', 'X', 'Y') and rating <- c('7.3','7.3', '7.3', '2.1', '2.1', '9.0','9.0', '9.0') and create a dataframe from it with: df <- data.frame(movieID, crewID, rating). And I do the following as you suggested:
m <- crossprod(table(df[-3]))
m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <-0
subset(as.data.frame.table(m), Freq > 0)

I get a table with rows A,B,C and columns A,B,C and each entry is 0.

Comment: @Christine, could you check that again, because after running the code exactly as presented, I get the correct values as depicted above. You must be doing something wrong. The `subset` function itself, gets values that are greater than 0. So there is no way you will have an entry of 0 in your final results

Comment: Yes, if I run only the first line of your code if returns a table with rows A,B,C and columns A,B,C and (A,A) is 9, (B,B) is 4 and (C,C) is 9. The other values are 0. As soon as I run the second line of your code I get the result I described before - an empty table, which obviously isn't changed by the last line of code.

Comment: @what happens when you just run `table(df[-3])`?

Comment: @Christine I see what you have. You should not have `A, B, C` but rather `V, X, Y, Z`. so try either `crossprod(table(df[1:2]))` or try `crossprod(table(df[2:1]))`. The one that gives you `V, X, Y, Z` as columns and rows is the one you need to use. Not `A, B, C`

Comment: It worked with ``crossprod(table(dataset[-2]))`` :) Thank you very much for your help and time! I appreciate it ^^

Comment: @Christine thats because the the order of the data you presented and the one you are using are different.

Comment: @Christine the data you have is the same. we are only interested in the `nconst, tconst` columns. Please break down my code slowly. ie try `table` then `crossprod` etc. Just play around the functiona nd data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient solution but this would be one way of doing it:

```
# Define a function that generates pairs of ids
make_pairs <- function(data){
# Extract all ids in the movie
data$crew %>% 
    # Organize them alphabetically
    sort() %>% 
    # Generate all unique pairs
    combn(2) %>% 
    # Prep for map
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    # Generate pairs as single string
    purrr::map_chr(str_flatten, '_')
}
# Generate the data
tibble::tibble(
movie = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B', "C", 'C', 'C'),
crew = c('Z', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'V', 'V', 'X', 'Y')
) %>% 
    # Nest the data so all ids in one movie gets put together
    tidyr::nest(data = -movie) %>%
    # Generate pairs of interactions
        dplyr::mutate(
        pairs = purrr::map(data, make_pairs)
    ) %>% 
    # Expand all pairs
    tidyr::unnest(cols = pairs) %>% 
    # Separate them into unique colums
    tidyr::separate(pairs, c('id1', 'id2')) %>% 
    # Count the number of times two ids co-occure
    dplyr::count(id1, id2)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  id1   id2       n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 V     X         1
2 V     Y         1
3 V     Z         1
4 X     Y         2
5 X     Z         1
6 Y     Z         1
```

Comment: Thank you! You're probably right - not necessarily the most efficient solution I assume, but it's working, which is better than what I could produce. I appreciate your help and time :)

Comment: It works fine on the small dataset, however, when I use my large dataset I get the error ``Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `pairs`.
i `pairs = purrr::map(data, make_pairs)`.
x n < m````

Comment: @Christine That means one movie has less then 2 crew members. I would suggest filtering them out first.